# Perl shell command cannot match @ symbol

Tags: regex, shell, perl, sh

I am trying to write a shell command, using perl, to do very basic checks on a string to see if it looks like an email address. Minimal reproducible example below:

```sh
# perl --version v5.28.1
perl -E 'exit 1 if "you@example.com" !~ /@/' || echo 'failed'
```

The above outputs `failed`. I understand that the `@` symbol is for denoting arrays in perl, but after searching it apparently it does not need escaping. Even if I escape it with a backslash the result is the same.

The question then is, why won't a sh run perl regex match an `@` symbol? Or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: try `perl -wE 'print "you@example.com\n";'`

Comment: @Mat Ahhh... thank you so much. If you add the details into an answer I am happy to accept that. That gives me everything I need. Sometimes all you need is a little nudge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong here is evident after running a command suggested by @Mat in the comments below the question.

```sh
$ perl -wE 'print "you@example.com\n";'
Possible unintended interpolation of @example in string at -e line 1.
Name "main::example" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
you.com
```

The string being matched is using double quotes, causing it to be interpolated. The interpolation converts the `@example` into an array reference but strips it out because it is undefined.

As such, the regular expression in the original question could not match the email because part of it was being stripped out during string interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

Why using a horse cart wheel when Goodyears are available in the [corner shop](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Valid)?

```
use Email::Valid;
my $address = Email::Valid->address('you@example.com');
exit $address ? 1 : 0;
```

Your original problem though, was a quoting issue. But you know that by now, I reckon from the comments.

Comment: I'm afraid this is being used in a configurable git hook, and people will be able to specify the regex they want to validate their author emails. I just need the basic regex for a sensible default. But you are right, generally better than rolling your own.